# Apache CXF (JAX-RS) with Spring Javaconfig and Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, cxf

How to setup Apache CXF with JAX-RS Spring Javaconfig and Jackson?
I have read
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html#SpringBoot-SpringBootCXFJAX-RSStarter and
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Jackson

It advises to use

```
<jaxrs:providers>
   <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

but I want to stay away from XML and use plain javaconfig.

My current configuration is

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {  
    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Server rsServer() {
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setBus(bus);
        endpoint.setAddress("/");
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(new MyService()));

        return endpoint.create();
    }   
}
```

Andpoint defined in my class MyService works, but when he is invoked I am getting message

> org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils    : No message body writer has
>   been found for class MyServiceResponse,
>   ContentType: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a json Provider bean. This will act as messageProvider. Your Application class should look like this.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {  
    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application .class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Server rsServer() {
        List<? extends Object> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        providers.add(getJsonProvider());
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        endpoint.setProviders(providers);
        endpoint.setBus(bus);
        endpoint.setAddress("/");
        endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.asList(new MyService())); 

        return endpoint.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider getJsonProvider() {
        new JacksonJsonProvider();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BartoszBilicki If this solved the problem, can you please accept it?

Comment: where are you returning your Server bean?

Comment: My ServiceBean does not have a default constructor, so I defined it as an Spring bean (and configured it using Spring), but then CXF warns that it can not instantiate the service (although I provided an instance of the service class not the class).